# Creating a directory with a name containing UTF-8 characters in Qt

Tags: utf-8, qt4, qdir

I am trying to create a directory that contains a UTF-8 characters using QDir::mkpath . A directory is created but the name is not correct. I am using this sample code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDir>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString path = QDir::homePath();
    path += QDir::separator();
    path += "محمود";
    QDir().mkpath(path);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by replacing

```
path += "محمود";
```

by

```
path += QString::fromUtf8("محمود");
```